# Is "application/*+json" a valid Accept header in HTTP

Tags: http, mime-types

The java spring framework's http client seems to default to sending this Accept header:

```
Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
```

I am curious about the "application/*+json" part. I believe the intention of this is to match any mime type that begins `application/` and ends `+json` - eg. `application/vnd.api+json`.

However looking at [RFC 7231 section 5.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) it says:

```
media-range    = ( "*/*"
                      / ( type "/" "*" )
                      / ( type "/" subtype )
                      ) *( OWS ";" OWS parameter )
```

which appears to specifically only allow * to be used instead of the subtype, not as part of it - suggesting that "application/*+json" should only match a mime type that actually as a * in the name.

The '+' syntax for mime types in general is defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6839 - however nothing in there would appear to allow it to be applied to wildcards as the HTTP RFC defines.

Is there some other RFC that widens the definition or is spring sending an erroneous Accept: header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer is "no". The allowable values for HTTP are defined in https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.5.3.2, and "*+json" is not a valid subtype (and even if it was, it would only match the subtype "*+json", not all subtypes ending in "+json").

Comment: I tend to agree: subtypes are by their grammar [tokens](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1) with no way to express a hierarchy. That being said, `*+json` is syntactically correct, yet unregistered as a subtype. Anyhow, `application/*+json` would match that literal string and not provoke any globbing as OP probably intended.